# How to skip the foreach loop based on the code given?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have a code check the checkedlistbox checkboxes in asp.net/c#.

```
foreach (ListItem item in cbxlFeatures.Items)
{
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       if (item.Value.Equals(row["Id"].ToString()))
        {
          item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Id"]); 
         // whenever this condition is met i need my 
         // loop to skip the remianing iterations and start with next one.

        }
         break;
     }
 }
```

**Update**

**I think , I was not clear in my question. Say I have 1 to 10 ids in my datatable. Where 7,8,9 have value false and rest true. And this id is too displaying on the checkboxlist. Just my true / false values differs. So What i asked to check the condition and set the value t/f to the checkbox. And the loop will skip once the check box is set to checked.**

Comment: Do you want to continue in the inner loop on `item == true` or are you saying you want to jump to the next checkbox and then ignore the row that was previously checked?

Comment: exactly... you got me,... Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keyword `continue;` as in below code

```
foreach (ListItem item in cbxlFeatures.Items)
{
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       if (item.Value.Equals(row["Id"].ToString()))
        {
          item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Id"]); 

          // this is what you need here
          continue;
        }
         break;
     }
 }
```

if you have more question let me know.

Thanks Ankur

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the keyword `continue;`

Comment: It's actually `continue`, not `Continue`.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the continue keyword

```
foreach (ListItem item in cbxlFeatures.Items)
{
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       if (item.Value.Equals(row["Id"].ToString()))
        {
          item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Id"]); 
         continue;

        }
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think , I was not clear in my question. Say I have 1 to 10 ids in my datatable. Where 7,8,9 have value false and rest true. And this id is too displaying on the checkboxlist. Just my true / false values differs. So What i asked to check the condition and set the value t/f to the checkbox. And the loop will skip once the check box is set to checked.

Comment: @Amit Then your sample code with `break` should work, so how is it not working?